# Asterik wildcard in string comparision

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to perform string matching using asterisk(*) wildcard in javascript. If user enters "v*v*k" then:

"vivek" should match.

There can be any number of asterisks. I implemented for a simple case where asterisk can be either at the starting,ending or middle position.

```
function matchString(pattern,columnValue)
{
    if(pattern.indexOf('*')>-1){
        if (pattern[0] == '*')
        {
            return columnValue.endsWith(pattern.substr(1,pattern.length - 1)) ? true:false
        }
        else if (pattern[pattern.length - 1] == '*')
        {
            return columnValue.startsWith(pattern.substr(0,pattern.length  -1)) ? true:false
        }else{
           var stringArray =  pattern.split('*')
           return columnValue.startsWith(stringArray[0]) &&  columnValue.endsWith(stringArray[stringArray.length-1]) ? true:false
        }
    }else{
       return (columnValue.indexOf(pattern)>-1)
    }
    return false;
}
```

I want to implement it using Regex so that any number of asteriks can be used at any position.

Comment: `"vv*k" -> "vivek"` should match. is that correct? or did you mean `"viv*k"`?

Comment: *"I want to implement it using Regex so that any number of asteriks can be used at any position."* If you run into a *specific* problem in the process, post a question about that. This question is far too broad/vague.

Answer (score 0):

if you meant "v**i**v*k" -> "vivek", how about:-

```js
function matchString(pattern,columnValue){
    var regex = new RegExp('^' + pattern.replace(/\*/g, '.{1}') + '$');
    return regex.test(columnValue);
}

alert('pattern = "*oo *a*", value = "foo bar", match = ' + matchString('*oo *a*', 'foo bar'));
```

**Edit**

Added ^ for start and $ for end

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't work that way. If I say n* it matches string that has 'n' in any position but it should return only that string that starts with n.

Comment: I have updated the answer